# Filter Pandas DataFrame depending on whether the filter value is specified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am trying to write a function that will return a series of DataFrame rows which satisfy some conditions.

To put it plainly, it looks something like this:

```
def get_measurement(measurements_base, data_selection, condition_id="", subject_id="", scan_type_id=""):
        measurement_path = data_selection[(data_selection["condition"] == condition_id)&(data_selection["subject"] == subject_id)&(data_selection["scan_type"] == scan_type_id)]["measurement"]
```

I would however like to have each condition (the statements separated by `&`) applied only if the variable being checked for is actually specified. Something like:

```
logical_set=[]
if condition_id:
    logical_set.extend((data_selection["condition"] == condition_id))
```

I am aware it won't work like this - but what would be a functioning and (if possible) elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first initialize an all-True Boolean selection mask, and update the mask with each specified condition:

```
# Assuming df is the input DataFrame
mask = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
if condition_id:
    mask &= df['condition_id'] == condition_id
if subject_id:
    mask &= ...
```

If you have many columns, it might be better to represent the conditions using a dictionary. Then, a more general selection function could be implemented as follows:

```
def get_measurement(df, conditions):
    mask = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
    for k, v in conditions.iteritems():
        mask &= (df[k] == v)
    return df[mask]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'measurement': [100,200,300]})
print df
print get_measurement(df, {'a': 1, 'b': 4})
```

Output:

```
# Input
   a  b  measurement
0  1  4          100
1  2  5          200
2  3  6          300

# Selected using {'a': 1, 'b': 4}
   a  b  measurement
0  1  4          100
```